# Webview not loading PDF file from Document Directory

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I want to show a PDF file in web view. For that I write code like:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"201507234Surat_GDCR.pdf"];

self.pdfWeb.hidden=FALSE;
self.JantriImage.hidden=TRUE;
self.pdfWeb.delegate=self;
self.pdfWeb = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight-64)];
self.pdfWeb.scalesPageToFit = YES;
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
NSString *encodedString=[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL];
[self.pdfWeb loadRequest:request];
```

Here `self.pdfWeb` is my webview and file is already in document directory but webview can't load file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"201507234Surat_GDCR.pdf”];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"201507234Surat_GDCR.pdf”];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];

if (success)
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  [webView loadRequest:request];

  webView.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAll;

}
```